# Clipped text on UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm using custom a font for UILabel but there is a strange problem, for some characters the text is being clipped:

[image]

The label should be like this (label frame has enlarged manually):

[image]

This is the code to add the label to the gray view:

```
let string = "کیخسروی"
let font = UIFont(name: "IranNastaliq", size: 30)!
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .font: font,
    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]


let mutabbleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
let rectSize = mutabbleAttributedString.size()
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rectSize.width, height: rectSize.height))
label.font = font
label.attributedText = mutabbleAttributedString
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
label.textAlignment = .center
let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let width = label.sizeThatFits(size).width
let height =  label.sizeThatFits(size).height
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
label.frame = frame
self.myView.addSubview(label)
label.center = self.myView.center
```

Seems `sizeThatFits()` does not calculate the bounds correctly.
I have to mention this clipping only happens while using some custom fonts.

Comment: It's seem like problem in your font

Comment: @SPatel there are several fonts with this problem

Comment: @Maysam: Is there any system font with this problem? BTW: Your size calculation is cumbersome and time-consuming. Use either `sizeToFit()` or compute the size only once.

Comment: @clemens No, it's only with custom fonts. I've tried ```sizeToFit()``` as well, it gives the same results. For now performance is not the case.

Comment: @Maysam: But `sizeToFit()` is much easier to use. ;) However, seems to be a problem with the specific shape of the text. Texts with such sweeping swings are extremely untypical for Latin scripts. Apparently the size calculation can't cope with the Farsi(?) font.

Comment: Yes, it's with Farsi/Arabic fonts

Comment: Fwiw Zapfino displays this same issue with the string "Hello World" - the d and even a little of the l are clipped at the trailing end…

Comment: You have to change the frame, or insets